# Counter example for $(A \times B) \cap (C \times D) = (A \cap C ) \times (B \cap D)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, proof-writing

I want to prove this:

$$(A \times B) \cap (C \times D) = (A \cap C ) \times (B \cap D)$$

by every element on LHS(left hand side) is an element of RHS and vice versa.

Does a counter example exist?

Comment: "I can prove this"  If you successfully prove it, then that means there aren't any counter examples.  "Is there a counter example exists?"  This is poor/incorrect grammar, suggesting that your question might be something else.  Perhaps you mean to ask "How can I prove this... Do there exist any counter examples."  The answer to that is by proving as you say that each element on the LHS is an element of the RHS, and that shows that counterexamples again can't exist.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a theorem. The proof is as follows.

\begin{align}
(x,y)\in(A\times B)\cap(C\times D)&\iff (x,y)\in(A\times B)\land (x,y)\in(C\times D)
\\
&\iff (x\in A \land y\in B) \land (x\in C \land y\in D)
\\
&\iff (x\in A \land x\in C) \land (y\in B \land y\in D)
\\
&\iff (x\in A \cap C) \land (y\in B \cap D)
\\
& \iff (x,y) \in (A \cap C) \times (B \cap D)
\end{align}