# no. of elements in $(B \times A) \cap (A \times B)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can someone prove that $n((A \times B) \cap (B \times A)) = n(A \cap B)^2$
I am unable to derive this. (Frankly, I don't know how to even start). I just let $(A \times B) = M, and (B \times A) = N$, and thus, their intersection can be written as

$n(M) + n(N) - n(M \cup N)$

=$2n(M) -n(M \cup N)$. If $n(A) = p, n(B) =q$, then $n(M)=n(N)=pq$.

Thus I get,

$n((A \times B) \cap (B \times A))= 2n(M) -n(M \cup N) = 2pq-n(M \cup N)$.

I do not know how to proceed

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is $AXB$..?

Comment: Cartesian product of 2 sets

Comment: You should probably write it as A \times B to get $A\times B$ in that case.

Comment: ohk...thanks buddy

Comment: No problem! $\,\,$

Comment: i suppose its done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use formula as in [Counter example for $(A \times B) \cap (C \times D) = (A \cap C ) \times (B \cap D)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1188926/counter-example-for-a-times-b-cap-c-times-d-a-cap-c-times-b-cap/1188931#1188931).

$n((A\times B)\cap (B\times A))=n((A\cap B)\times (B\cap A))=n(A\cap B)^2$

Comment: thanks mate! quite useful formula, I daresay!

Answer (score 1):

By definition $(x,y)\in (A\times B)$ means, $x\in A$ and $y\in B$. For this element to lie in the intersection we need also $x\in B, y\in A$. So this show that this intersection is $(A\cap B)\times (A\cap B)$ where the number of elements is $n(A\cap B)^2$.